# Branching on uniform vs texture lookup

Tags: opengl, glsl

In a fragment shader, which of these is likely to be faster?

```
vec3 val = vec3(0);
if (bool(uform)) {
     val = texture(tex, texcoord).rgb;
}
```

or

```
vec3 val = texture(tex, texcoord).rgb * uform;
```

"uform" is an int that will be either 0 or 1.

I've been using the first one, but I've heard plenty of times that branching should be avoided. On my system, (nvidia 680) I can't really notice a difference between the two, but on most recent systems, which one would likely be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shader compiler is free to optimize the first to

```
vec3 val = texture(tex, texcoord).rgb * sign(abs(uform));
```

which is also branch-less. However it is not guaranteed to do so.

So on a sufficiently optimizing driver the difference will be minimal.

Though some compiler can optimize the flow if it is all dependent on uniforms. What will happen is the the driver will recompile and reoptimize the program with all uniforms inlined. This usually happens to eliminate branches but is fully implementation defined.

Comment: So, your saying that in all cases, it will still do the texture lookup? If that's so, would it be best to just use the second option in the first place? Also, wouldn't that mean that branching on a uniform is more expensive than any amount of texture lookups?

Comment: @Jagoly: A texture lookup with a uniform/vertex attribute (static) coordinate is cheap, the GPU can pre-fetch and cache the memory because it knows which are of the texture is going to be looked up when it starts a group of fragment shader executions. I couldn't say whether branching would be more expensive, but I can say that there are forms of texture lookups that are more expensive than others (such as when you dynamically compute the texture coordinates at run-time -- called _dependent lookups_). Avoiding a dependent lookup with a branch is probably worthwhile.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Ah! That hadn't occurred to me. I was thinking about how that would apply to branching (eg, if dynamic), but not that it would apply to the texture lookups as well, which makes sense now that you've mentioned it. Thanks!